# Self modification for method's parameters in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I make this work?

```
def change_method_parameter(instance1, method1, param1)
   instance1.define_singleton_method method1 do |param1|
     instance1.method1(param1)
   end 
end
```

The idea would be a method that allows you to change the parameters of other methods

Comment: define what you mean by "change the parameters". Do you mean something like, append something to a string or multiply a number, before passing it to the other function?

Comment: No.. I mean like.. Suppose you have:
 def foo(param)
puts(param) 
end

And I now want to hardcode "hey" in param1